# MySQL selecting week number and year causes problems with last week of year

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

I have a large dataset spanning several years and I am having problems getting a string such as "53-2016" (week 53 in 2016).

My query is:

```
SELECT 
  date,
  DATE_FORMAT(date, "%v-%Y") AS week,      
FROM myTable
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY date;
```

Using this query I get two rows where I would like to only have one.

This happens because of `GROUP BY week`. At the end of 2015 the dates: 28-31 of December are added to week 53-2015 where the rest of the week (1-3 of January) are added to a row called 53-2016.

Is there any way that I can add the first three days of January to the group 53-2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out by myself.

Turns out MySQL has a second way to print year in `DATE_FORMAT()`.

> %x - Year for the week where Monday is the first day of week, four digits, used with %v

This solved the problem, and my query ended up as:

```
SELECT 
  date,
  DATE_FORMAT(date, "%v-%x") AS week,      
FROM myTable
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.
Do the following

```
SELECT 
  date,
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL MOD(DAYOFWEEK(`date`) +5,7) DAY ), "%v-%Y") AS week
FROM myTable
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY date;
```

This will query day of the week, and will subtract the days so every day basically is truncated to the previous monday

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (do more test...)?

```
#DROP TABLE TT1;
CREATE TABLE TT1 (date datetime);

INSERT INTO TT1 values ('2015-12-31');
INSERT INTO TT1 values ('2016-01-01');
SELECT 
  date,
    CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(date, "%v")  , '-', CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, "%v")>52 AND DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m")=1 THEN DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y")-1 ELSE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y") END ) AS week      
FROM TT1;

DROP TABLE TT1;
```

Output:

```
    date    week
1   31.12.2015 00:00:00 53-2015
2   01.01.2016 00:00:00 53-2015
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your query has problems with the week from 2016 to 2017, but I manged to solve my problem and have posted an answer.